# Flutter AdMob | The app starts to lag after implementing ads

Tags: android, flutter, dart, admob, ads

I'm working on an audiobook listening app. There I have my main page, which consists of 3 page widgets linked through a Page View that I can swipe to navigate through these pages. On each page I have laid exactly one banner ad from `google_mobile_ads` package. The problem is that if I add those 3 banners, my app starts to lag a lot, I did check the release version of my app, it is still laggy. In order to understand better the situation I will explain how my ad loading works.
I have a file, where I store the classes regarding those banner ads:

```
import 'package:google_mobile_ads/google_mobile_ads.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

late AnchoredAdaptiveBannerAdSize adaptiveBannerSize;

class AdWidgets {
  static Container? libraryPag;
  static Container? homePag;
  static Container? settingsPag;
}

void _setLoaded() {
  AdState.loaded = true;
}

class AdState {
  static bool loaded = false;
  late Future<InitializationStatus> initialization;
  AdState(this.initialization);
  String get bannerAdUnitId => 'ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/6300978111';
  BannerAdListener get adListener => _adListener;


  BannerAdListener _adListener = BannerAdListener(
    onAdLoaded: (ad) {
      _setLoaded();
    }
  );
}
```

There is the `AdState` class which I use to load my banner ads by providing them a `BannerAdListener` and an `AdUnitId`, the `bool loaded` is used in the widgets that display those banners in order for them to know if the ads where loaded and can be displayed properly.

Next I have a Stateful Widget `Content`, that I use to navigate through my app routes:

```
class _ContentState extends State<Content> with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {

  @override
  void didChangeDependencies() {
    // TODO: implement didChangeDependencies
    super.didChangeDependencies();
    final adState = Provider.of<AdState>(context);
    adState.initialization.then((status) {
      AdWidgets.libraryPag = Container(
          width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
          height: adaptiveBannerSize.height.toDouble(),
          child: AdWidget(
            ad: BannerAd(
                adUnitId: adState.bannerAdUnitId,
                size: adaptiveBannerSize,
                request: AdRequest(),
                listener: adState.adListener
            )
              ..load(),
          )
      );
      AdWidgets.homePag = Container(
        width: 320,
        height: 100,
        child: AdWidget(ad: BannerAd(
            adUnitId: adState.bannerAdUnitId,
            size: AdSize.largeBanner,
            request: AdRequest(),
            listener: adState.adListener
        )
          ..load()),
      );
      AdWidgets.settingsPag = Container(
          width: 320,
          height: 250,
          child: AdWidget(ad: BannerAd(
              adUnitId: adState.bannerAdUnitId,
              size: AdSize.mediumRectangle,
              request: AdRequest(),
              listener: adState.adListener
          )
            ..load()
          )
      );
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ValueListenableBuilder(
      valueListenable: Settings.theme,
      builder: (context, value, _) {
        SystemChrome.setSystemUIOverlayStyle(SystemUiOverlayStyle(
          statusBarColor: Colors.transparent,
          statusBarIconBrightness: Settings.theme.value == 'Dark' ? Brightness.light : Brightness.dark,
        ));
        return WillPopScope(
            onWillPop: () async {
              if (bottomBarIndex.value != 1) {
                moveHome();
              }
              return false;
            },
            child: Scaffold(
              resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,
              body: Navigator(
                key: Content.contentNavigatorKey,
                initialRoute: '/',
                onGenerateRoute: (RouteSettings settings) {
                  Widget builder;
                  switch (settings.name) {
                    case '/':
                      builder = MainPage();
                      break;
                    case '/bookPage':
                      Book book = settings.arguments as Book;
                      builder = BookPage(book: book);
                      bottomBarIndex.value = -1;
                      break;
                    case '/addBook':
                      builder = AddBookPage();
                      bottomBarIndex.value = -1;
                      break;
                    case '/changeCover':
                      Book book = settings.arguments as Book;
                      builder = ChangeCoverPage(book: book);
                      bottomBarIndex.value = -1;
                      break;
                    default:
                      throw Exception('Invalid route: ${settings.name}');
                  }
                  return PageRouteBuilder(
                      transitionDuration: Duration(milliseconds: 300),
                      transitionsBuilder:
                          (context, animation, secAnimation, child) {
                        animation = CurvedAnimation(
                            parent: animation, curve: Curves.easeIn);
                        return FadeTransition(
                          opacity: animation,
                          child: child,
                        );
                      },
                      pageBuilder: (context, animation, secAnimation) {
                        return builder;
                      });
                },
                onPopPage: (route, result) {
                  return route.didPop(result);
                },
              ),
            ));
      },
    );
  }
}
```

In the didChangeDependencies method I initialize the adState (the way it is done in the Monetizing apps with Flutter official tutorial) and then assign three banner widgets to the each of the `static Container` from the `AdWidgets` custom class. Then I just display those Containers as I please, for example:

```
class LibraryPage extends StatefulWidget{
  const LibraryPage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _LibraryPageState createState() => _LibraryPageState();
}

class _LibraryPageState extends State<LibraryPage> with TickerProviderStateMixin  {

  late TabController _tabController;
  late AppBar appBar;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _tabController = TabController(length: 3, vsync: this);
    appBar = AppBar(
      brightness: Settings.theme.value == 'Dark' ? Brightness.dark : Brightness.light,
      shadowColor: Settings.theme.value == 'Dark' ? Color.fromRGBO(0, 0, 0, 0.1) : Color.fromRGBO(0, 0, 0, 0.5),
      backgroundColor: Settings.colors[2],
      title: Text('Library'),
      bottom: TabBar(
        controller: _tabController,
        labelPadding: EdgeInsets.zero,
        labelStyle: TextStyle(
            fontFamily: 'Montserrat',
            fontWeight: FontWeight.w500
        ),
        labelColor: Settings.colors[3],
        indicator: UnderlineTabIndicator(
            borderSide: BorderSide(color: Settings.colors[3], width: 2)
        ),
        tabs: [
          Tab(
            text: 'Reading',
          ),
          Tab(
            text: 'New',
          ),
          Tab(
            text: 'Read',
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Settings.colors[1],
      resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,
      appBar: appBar,
      body: Column(
        children: [
          if (AdWidgets.libraryPag != null && AdState.loaded)
            AdWidgets.libraryPag!
          else
            Container(
              width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
              height: adaptiveBannerSize.height.toDouble(),
              color: Settings.colors[0],
              child: Center(
                  child: Text(
                    'Ad not loaded',
                    style: TextStyle(
                        color: Settings.colors[4],
                        fontFamily: 'Open Sans'),
                  )),
            ),
          ScrollConfiguration(
            behavior: MyBehavior(),
            child: SizedBox(
              width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
              height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height - appBar.preferredSize.height - appBar.bottom!.preferredSize.height - adaptiveBannerSize.height,
              child: TabBarView(
                controller: _tabController,
                children: [
                  Category(category: 'reading'),
                  Category(category: 'new'),
                  Category(category: 'read')
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

As you can see there, I check if the `AdWidgets.libraryPag` is not null and if the ad was loaded and then if true - I display my ad.

The major issue is that - when I navigate from one page to another or scroll down it is very  laggy even in the release build, also my bottomNavBar starts flickering a lot. Also when I do any kind of action in my app I get a stack of messages in of the console log saying `D/AudioManager(30711): getStreamVolume isRestricted mode = 0`. My guess is that the ads are reloading too often causing some performance issues.

Here is a small portion of my console log:

```
W/ContentCatcher(30711): Failed to notify a WebView
W/Choreographer(30711): Already have a pending vsync event.  There should only be one at a time.
W/Choreographer(30711): OPTS_INPUT: First frame was drawed before optimized, so skip!
W/ContentCatcher(30711): Failed to notify a WebView
W/ContentCatcher(30711): Failed to notify a WebView
W/Choreographer(30711): Already have a pending vsync event.  There should only be one at a time.
W/Choreographer(30711): Already have a pending vsync event.  There should only be one at a time.
W/ContentCatcher(30711): Failed to notify a WebView
W/ContentCatcher(30711): Failed to notify a WebView
W/Choreographer(30711): OPTS_INPUT: First frame was drawed before optimized, so skip!
W/Choreographer(30711): OPTS_INPUT: First frame was drawed before optimized, so skip!
W/ContentCatcher(30711): Failed to notify a WebView
I/Ads     (30711): Use RequestConfiguration.Builder().setTestDeviceIds(Arrays.asList("B0B49AF69923DB48675A21F6F88D2525")) to get test ads on this device.
D/AudioManager(30711): getStreamVolume isRestricted mode = 0
D/AudioManager(30711): getStreamVolume isRestricted mode = 0
```

How can I fix this performance issue?

Answer (score 5):

Refer to [this](https://github.com/googleads/googleads-mobile-flutter/issues/80#issuecomment-797573555) answer on issue,
**Prior to Android 10 AndroidView Should have better performance. if this is the case, maybe we can check the device OS and use AndroidView Instead of PlatformViewLink.**

**atrope** make fork from repo **google_mobile_ads** and do this trick for better performance for device  os less than Android 10

Use this repo instead of official google_ads in your pubspec.yaml

```
  google_mobile_ads:
    git:
      url: https://github.com/SuaMusica/googleads-mobile-flutter.git
      path: packages/google_mobile_ads
      ref: feature/suamusica
```

Special thanks for [atrope](https://github.com/atrope)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is not in your implementation or code. It is because the package is using `androidView` which is very expensive when handled by devices with android below 10. You can force flutter to switch to `platformviewlink` like this and it will fix the issue for the moment.

```
 if (Platform.isAndroid) {
androidInfo = await DeviceInfoPlugin().androidInfo;
final isAndroidOld = (androidInfo.version.sdkInt ?? 0) < 29; //Android 10
useHybridComposition = remoteConfig.getBool(
  isAndroidOld
      ? RemoteConfigKey.useHybridCompositionOlderOS
      : RemoteConfigKey.useHybridCompositionNewerOS,
);
if (isAndroidOld && useHybridComposition) {
  await PlatformViewsService.synchronizeToNativeViewHierarchy(false);
}
```

}

Comment: Thanks ,but  where should i place this code ,I have used Mahmoud Abu Elheja solution and it works like a charm. but i don't want to rely on  unofficial package so i will be grateful if  you help me.

Comment: this should be added in your main function at the start of the app

Comment: what plugin you used?